# Flash and Chrome render bug

Tags: flash, apache-flex, google-chrome, bitmap, render

I have a strange issue where Flash Player in Chrome is not updating unless the browser is resized. The app is an online design tool, written in Flex, and one of the features allows the user to upload an image and crop it. The image loads fine, and the crop action does not reload the image but uses Bitmap.copyPixels to create the cropped version.

When I test on localhost (though a local server not just straight from the file system) the issue does not happen. However on our QA server the image does not appear unless you resize the browser, when I suppose a screen refresh is forced.

I've tried all the usual suspects in AS3/Flex to force a redraw, updateAfterEvent, invalidateDisplayList, etc.

One hacky solution we came up with is to resize the browser by a pixel, but this is obviously not ideal and I'd prefer a solution to a work-around :)

thanks!

Here's the Bitmap code for reference...

```
var cropData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( _crop.width, _crop.height );
var originalData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( _loader.width, _loader.height );
originalData.draw( _loader );
cropData.copyPixels( originalData, _crop, new Point() );

var crop:Bitmap = new Bitmap( cropData );
crop.smoothing = true;
this.addChild( crop );

if ( _width > 0 && _height > 0 ) 
{
    crop.width = _width;
    crop.height = _height;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what your issue is.  What sort of updating are you expecting to see?  How is that update being triggered?  Since it works in one environment, but not the other, my first impulse is that this is not a bug; but there is something different between the two environments that causes the issue.

Comment: Loader and container code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash player was embedded with the wmode param set to 'opaque', with this setting there seems to be an occasional bug in flash player for Chrome in which closing a Flex mx:Panel component does not result in the screen being updated.

Removing the wmode parameter fixes the issue above but the bug remains.

Answer (score 2):

My first impulse is that the compilers of your two environments are different.I once found that results compiled by Flash Builder and mxmlc under Linux box are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a enterFrame event to "this" and moving the crop bitmap around to see what happens. From the looks of it, it's a bug on flash/chrome. Does it work on the other browsers?

**EDIT:**

Try adding this and see what happens:

```
var crop:Bitmap = new Bitmap( cropData );
crop.smoothing = true;
this["cropTest"] = crop; // Add this
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrameTest); // Add this
this.addChild( crop );

// Add this function
protected function onEnterFrameTest(evt : Event) : void {
    this["cropTest"].x += this["cropTest"].x > 0 ? -1 : 1;
}
```

If it gives an error, just switch this["cropTest"] with a declared variable on this.

**EDIT2:**

Replace all your shown code with the following:

```
this["loaderTest"] = _loader;
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrameTest); // Add this

// Add this function
protected function onEnterFrameTest(evt : Event) : void {
    this.removeEventListener(onEnterFrameTest);

    var _loader = this["loaderTest"];
    var cropData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( _crop.width, _crop.height );
    var originalData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( _loader.width, _loader.height );
    originalData.draw( _loader );
    cropData.copyPixels( originalData, _crop, new Point() );

    var crop:Bitmap = new Bitmap( cropData );
    crop.smoothing = true;
    this.addChild( crop );

    if ( _width > 0 && _height > 0 ) 
    {
        crop.width = _width;
        crop.height = _height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, unfortunately the render bug still happens. No image appears until I resize the browser, then I see it doing the x position dance above :)

Comment: If you use originalData as the content of the bitmap, 'var crop:Bitmap = new Bitmap( originalData );' what happens?

Comment: Same result, no image until chrome resize. I'm going to try a straight AS3 project, rather than Flex to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Good idea, but same result. Tried a timer as well. I also tried a AS3 project with the bitmap crop and it works fine. I think the issue may be that a flex Panel is open above the Sprite, it's almost as if the panel saves what was underneath when it popped open, so any changes while it is open aren't rendered.

Comment: If the Panel is influencing the results, couldn't you force an update on the panel somehow? Flex isn't my thing, but there must be some way to identify the problem and force a refresh.

Comment: Fixed it, but it's not an ideal solution. The SWF was embedded with wmode: "opaque" so that Flash wouldn't always take the highest layer. Removing that property fixes the Chrome issue, but removes the ability to have elements over the Flash Player. It's a Chrome bug (or maybe I should say Adobe's bug in Chrome) as it doesn't happen in other browsers.

Comment: Congratulations, awesome that you fixed it. Too bad I couldn't be of more assistance.